# Logitech DiNovo Edge Bluetooth keyboard lag

Tags: bluetooth, lag, logitech-keyboard

I just bought myself a Logitech DiNovo Edge to use on my HTPC. Whenever I use the touch pad or hit a key, there is a delay (a little less than half a second, I'd guess) before the computer reacts - and this is seriously annoying.

It's not that kind of "wake up"-lag when I haven't used it for a minute, because that I'd sort of expect. This is all the time. I've been searching 'round the internets, but with no luck so far. Seems to me that other people experience this with other Bluetooth devices, but is there some universal solution for this?

Running Windows 7, newest drivers and using the Bluetooth dongle that came with the keyboard. Distance of use is about 2-3 meters, but the problem stays the same no matter how close i get to the dongle, so this should not be a problem.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth operates in the same frequency band as 802.11b/g wireless so is there a wireless access point or wireless antenna close to the bluetooth dongle or keyboard? If so, the AP may be affecting transmission/reception. One quick check would be to switch off the wireless and/or shift its channel and see what happens.

DECT phones, wireless video senders, desktop halogen lamps and microwave ovens are also possible interference sources so see if there's any likely candidates nearby and turn them off for a short while too.

for what it's worth, I used to have one of those keyboards at work on a HTPC (Acer Veriton L410) dual core PC running Vista in a training room and it worked fine over a distance of about 4 metres with the default drivers.

Comment: There is a wireless router nearby, but the problem remained the same even when I turned it completely off.

Comment: Can you try the keyboard on another PC to see if the problem travels with it?